# pg_restore changing object owner not working ,

Tags: postgresql, database, restore

I just try the solution found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469008/postgresql-backup-database-and-restore-on-different-owner

And I still have an error on the inexistent object owner.

What I do:

```
pg_dump -F c -f fnam.sql.tgz -h postgresql.bizinnov.net -U bizinnov bizinnov_fnam
pg_restore -F c --clean --no-owner --role=fnam -h localhost -U fnam -d fnam_db1 fnam.sql.tgz
```

What I get:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 148; 1259 408716672
>   SEQUENCE auth_group_id_seq bizinnov
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  sequence "auth_group_id_seq" does not exist
>       Command was: DROP SEQUENCE public.auth_group_id_seq;
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 149; 1259 408716674
>   TABLE auth_group bizinnov
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not
>   execute query: ERROR:  table "auth_group" does not exist
>       Command was: DROP TABLE public.auth_group;
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 6; 2615 2200 SCHEMA
>   public postgres
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query:
>   ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
>       Command was: DROP SCHEMA public;
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema
>   "public" already exists
>       Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2029; 0 0 COMMENT
>   SCHEMA public postgres
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute
>   query: ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
>       Command was: COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';
>
> pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
>
> pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
>
> pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2030; 0 0 ACL public postgres
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: **ERROR: role "bizinnov" does not exist**
>       Command was: REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
>
> REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
>
> GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO
>
> postgres; ... WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 125